# How to remove postgres user password for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

how to remove default password for postgres user?
**config/database.yml**

```
default: &default
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  adapter: postgresql

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_dev
```

**/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf**

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Error: no password supplied on rails s
That's why I use custom login/password for every new rails project

**How to fix this? I want to use default postgres user without password**

Answer (score 0):

Your given ERROR message seems to be approximate, I don't think PostgreSQL would provide that exact error message.

You don't appear to be specifying a username to connect as.  So by default it is probably attempting to connect as the PostgreSQL user which has the same spelling as the OS user running your app process.  This is unlikely to be 'postgres'.  If you want to connect as the PostgreSQL user 'postgres', specify that as the username. Don't rely on the default, which is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change all USER `status to trust` in **pg_hba.conf**. In this way it will not require any password and will work fine. Although it is not a good practice but it is ok on the local server.

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoHRH.png)

Or you can change the password by typing these following commands from your terminal.

```
psql -U postgres
\password
Enter new password: ***
Enter it again: ***
```